# Is this use of PHP eval() exploitable?

Tags: web-application, php

During a code review, I have found something similar to this:

```
function foo() {

        $a = "a";
        $expression = '$_GET["$a"]';

        return eval('return ('.$expression.');');
}

$a = foo();
echo $a;
```

Don't mind the nonsense, the example is simplified and due to bad design decisions, the client "really" needs the "return eval" instruction.

My guess would be no, because `$expression` is not `$_GET["$a"]`, but a string representing the name of the variable, so the argument to `eval()` is equivalent to a "return string".

But according to the PHP manual:

> You should never use parentheses around your return variable when returning by reference, as this will not work. You can only return variables by reference, not the result of a statement. If you use `return ($a);` then you're not returning a variable, **but the result of the expression `($a)`** (which is, of course, the value of `$a`).

Is there a way this could be exploited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you just echo a GET variable, this is vulnerable to XSS. But that has nothing to do with your use of `eval` which I take is the main focus of the question. So let's look at that.

If you replace `eval(...)` with `echo ...`, you will note that no matter what you pass in, the output will be this:

```
return ($_GET["$a"]);
```

This is because you use `'` and not `"`, so `$expression` does not end up conatining the value of the GET variable. So there is nothing controlled by the user in the expression you are evaluating - It's basically just a constant. That's not dangerous (given that the constant itself doesn't contain dangerous code), but it's not exactly useful either. You might as well just drop the `eval`.

But still... I would be nervous if I was responsible for this code. It sure looks shaky, and just using `eval` no matter why is a huge red flag. Plus, who knows what I might have missed in this answer.

Comment: You can still get reflective XSS here.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo That's a very relevant point - I have edited my answer. Thanks!